# nsenter error:_nl_intern_locale_data: Assertion failed

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-machine

I am trying to work with `nsenter` in docker but getting the above error from morning.

I have upgraded locales as well but still getting the same error
command which I am trying to execute is

```
sudo nsenter -m 29050 /bin/bash
```

The error I am getting after execution of the same command is

> ```
> nsenter: loadlocale.c:129: _nl_intern_locale_data: Assertion `cnt < (sizeof (_nl_value_type_LC_TIME) / sizeof (_nl_value_type_LC_TIME[0]))' failed.
>     Aborted.
> ```

Kindly help me in solving the problem.

Thanks.

Comment: Interesting enough, I had the same error from `flex` when trying to do a build of Android 7.1 AOSP. "flex-2.5.39: loadlocale.c:130: _nl_intern_local_data: Assertion 'cnt < (sizeof (_nl_value_type_LC_TIME) / sizeof (_no_value_type_LC_TIME[0]))' failed.". I used `export LC_ALL=C` from the command line and then redid `make` with `m -j2` and it continued doing the build.

Answer (score 5):

Setting LC_ALL="C.UTF-8" will probably fix your problem.

Answer (score 1):

First, edit /etc/locale.gen and add the locales you want.

Make sure the utf8 in the locale name is lowercase, not e.g. UTF-8.

Make sure in your startup files like ~/.bash_profile and ~/.bashrc etc. you set LANG and related variables to the lowercase utf8 form, see the directories in /usr/lib/locale for the correct form.

**Refer this link** -> https://askubuntu.com/questions/1081901/what-is-the-correct-way-to-fix-an-assertion-in-loadlocale-c

Comment: Thanks for the link to the posted question on askubuntu.com.